# How to apply the style according to row in jQuery

Tags: jquery

[image]

I have created a loop over the `Div` and I have given them different `id` for Example `(div [id]=" 'wave' + i " )`, `(div [id]=" 'wave1' + i " )` so on, The given requirement is when you click on the button which is located in front of Each row then style applies to that particular row So I have applied the logic below which I feel static and long, can someone help me which another logic which is dynamic and less.

```
 AllokVertical(name) {
    // console.log("name is ",name)
    this.buttonpressedData.forEach((ele) => {
      if (name === "Test1") {
        var i = 0
        if (ele.id === `wave${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 2}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 3}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 4}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 5}${i}`) {
          $('#' + ele.id).removeClass('yellow')
        }

      } else if (name === "Test2") {
        var i = 1
        if (ele.id === `wave${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 2}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 3}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 4}${i}`) {
          $('#' + ele.id).removeClass('yellow')
        }

      } else if (name === "Test3") {
        var i = 2
        if (ele.id === `wave${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i - 1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 2}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 3}${i}`) {
          $('#' + ele.id).removeClass('yellow')
        }
      }else if (name === "Test4") {
        var i = 3
        if (ele.id === `wave${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i - 2}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i-1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i+1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 2}${i}`) {
          $('#' + ele.id).removeClass('yellow')
        }
      }else if (name === "Test5") {
        var i = 4
        if (ele.id === `wave${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i - 3}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i-2}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i-1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i + 1}${i}`) {
          $('#' + ele.id).removeClass('yellow')
        }
      }else {
        var i = 5
        if (ele.id === `wave${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i - 4}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i-3}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i-2}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i-1}${i}` || ele.id === `wave${i}${i}`) {
          $('#' + ele.id).removeClass('yellow')
        }
      }

    })
  }
```

Comment: please share some html too

Comment: @VilsadPP see the HTML And i have given different id name because i want to change the color of that div based on click of that particular div.

Comment: Hi, i have  uploaded the image on the top you can find it , if i click All Ok then that particular row should affect By horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a data-name attribute to the dive and then use that in query to find the clicked row, you can add the class to the matching element and remove the same from others.

```
<div data-name="{{data1.comments}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title={{data1.comments}} [id]=" 'wave' + i " (click)="openmodel('wave' + i,'Google')"  class="buttoncolor row">
     <p class="innerText">{{data1.Google}}</p>
</div>
```

in code

```
AllokVertical(name) {
    $('.row').removeClass('yellow');
    $('*[data-name="'+name+'"]').addClass('yellow');
}
```

this is the idea, you can work on this to achieve your desired effect

Comment: This is applying all from horizontally i want to apply the styles vertically

Comment: if you want to apply styles vertically, you can add data attributes to the cells to categories and then use that to apply style.

Comment: Yah its working now, Thanks for the solutions @Vilsad